# jQuery's .blur() not fired when clicking on li

Tags: javascript, jquery

So we have a `<ul>` which contains several `<li>`s, and a `<textarea>`. The `<textarea>` has a `.blur()` event handler which works as expected when clicking outside. However, if I set focus on the `<textarea>`, then click on one of the `<li>`s to make the `<textarea>` lose focus, `.blur()` is not fired. Any idea why this happens and how to make it work?

Code:

```
$("textarea").blur(function(e) {
// Do something
});
```

By the way, the `<li>` has no `.click()` handler.

Environment: Mac OS X 10.9, Chrome 46.

Comment: Add your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Only a few browsers support/detect the blur event on non-form elements. But, of course, you can always trigger an event by yourself or as a reaction. See here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zrsjxs0/)

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div>here is the div</div>
<strong>here is the strong</strong>

$('textarea').blur(function() {
    alert('ta blur');
});
$('div').blur(function() {
    alert('div blur');
});
$('strong').blur(function() {
    alert('strong blur');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('strong').trigger('blur');
});
```